# laravel : form model binding get null so got error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**this is my homecontroller :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Models\Profile as Profile;
use Auth;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $profile = Profile::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
        return view('home.index')->with("profile", $profile);
    }
}
```

**and it is my view ( partial of some ) :**

```
<img src="{{ $profile ?: url('images/'.$profile->logo) }}" alt="Profile-Image" class="img-circle" width="44">
{{ $profile->company_name ?: Auth::user()->username}}
```

**this my Profiles table :**

### user_id | company_name | logo

2    |     deneme   | zoro.jpg

as you see i have no data which has user_id = 1 so $profile values not coming from db and than i got this error :

```
Trying to get property of non-object
(View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/works/menu/resources/views/layout/header.blade.php)
(View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/works/menu/resources/views/layout/header.blade.php)
(View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/works/menu/resources/views/layout/header.blade.php)
```

what can i do now ?

Comment: are you sure the user is authenticated?

Comment: @MinaAbadir, yes i am

Comment: @MinaAbadir user must not has informatin so the user when comes to the profile page all inputs come empty. you understood me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it in your view:

```
<img src="{{ !$profile ?: url('images/'.$profile->logo) }}" alt="Profile-Image" class="img-circle" width="44">
{{ $profile->company_name ?: Auth::user()->username}}
```